# Google Sheets QUERY function with return unique values based on year

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to query a table in google sheets and return all columns and unique values which match specific criteria (Year Column):

From this:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

To this desidered output:
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Comment: So you want sum or want to show as like screenshot `300+100...`

Comment: Like the screenshot

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far, and a sample sheet.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rvJttVtovBb5AdhUuZMNLfwvz6NMcvcFBkNwecT_duQ/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you give the columns names

```
=query(A1:D4,"SELECT A, C, SUM(D) GROUP BY A, C",1)
```

[image]

Comment: It is not my expected result https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rvJttVtovBb5AdhUuZMNLfwvz6NMcvcFBkNwecT_duQ/edit#gid=0
If you see the question the green table must to contain col K as "n" + "n" (not sum) and col L as "n" + "n" (not sum)

Comment: Feel free to work it yourself, this is not what QUERY() or SQL is designed to accomplish. A thank you for my effort would have also been nice. People answering here are not paid and volunteer their own time and knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`QUERY()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) function. The [query language](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage) is case sensitive, remember this when writing the query in the `QUERY` function.

Perhaps re arranging your data, and using also the [`CONCATENATE()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094123?hl=en) function might be of help.